# How to get value of an attribute from django model

Tags: django

I have a list of products:

```
product_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

and I want to know the total quantity of these product that I have in my `AllotmentDocket`  Model

Models.py

```
class AllotmentDocket(models.Model):

    transaction_no = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    product1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    product1_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    product2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    product2_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    product3 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    product3_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    product4 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    product4_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    product5 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    product5_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    product6 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    product6_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    product7 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    product7_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    product8 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    product8_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

allotment_dockets = AllotmentDocket.objects.annotate(total_quantity=F('product1_quantity')+F('product2_quantity')+F('product3_quantity')+F('product4_quantity')+F('product5_quantity')+F('product6_quantity')+F('product7_quantity')+F('product8_quantity'))

print(allotment_dockets.values('total_quantity'))
```

If you want to get sum of `total_quantity` for all `AllotmentDocket`, then use [**`aggregation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
total = allotment_dockets.aggregate(total=Sum('total_quantity'))['total']

print(total)
```

### For product wise quantity

IMHO, your model design is not correct. Your product should be a separate model and it should be connected to AllotmentDocket via ForeignKey or M2M. Anyhow, I think you can take this approach:

```
product_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
product_model_fields = ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4',...# so on]

total = 0
item_wise_quantity = {}

for product in product_list:
   for field in product_model_fields:
        query = {field:product}
        items = AllotmentDocket.objects.filter(**query)
        for item in items:
            quantity = getattr(item, field+'_quantity')
            total += quantity
            item_wise_quantity[product] = item_wise_quantity.get(product, 0) + quantity

print(item_wise_quantity)
```

### Optimum model design

```
# model

class AllotmentDocket(models.Model):
    transaction_no = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField("Product", through="ProductAllotment")

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ProductAllotment(models.Model):
    allotment = models.ForeignKey(AllotmentDocket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="allotments")
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

# query

product_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

products = Product.objects.filter(name__in=product_list).annotate(sum_product=Sum('allotments__quantity')
# individual product quantity
products.values('name','sum_product')
# total sum
products.aggregate(sum=Sum('sum_product'))['sum']
```

Comment: Actually i want to get product-wise quantity and their total, how can I get that ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly! and how can I get the products with quantity if I had `ForeignKey` relation in my model ? Can you please show that too ?

Comment: I posted another question in which `ForeignKey` relation is present, please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60900491/get-values-of-foreignkey-related-objects-in-django